# Как сохранить Java Date в Mysql timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

Отображение даты в сервлете у меня формата: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S.
И если я попытаюсь сохранить в таком виде получу ошибку HTTP Status 400 -.
Дата сохраняется только в формате yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.Как это исправить?

Comment: Чем пользуетесь для подключение к бд?

Comment: с помощью hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200972/hibernate-date-dont-save-the-milliseconds) пишут, что проблема в самом Date.(блин, чож я забыл что он все в секундах хранит) Нужно использовать `java.sql.Timestamp`

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
```